# reCaptcha v1 suddenly stopped working in cordova-based app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, recaptcha

our Cordova-based app in prod uses reCaptcha v1.
I've seen that it must be updated or it will stop working after 31 March as said here:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

> What happens to reCAPTCHA v1? Any calls to the v1 API will not work
>   after March 31, 2018. Starting in November 2017, a percentage of
>   reCAPTCHA v1 traffic will begin to show a notice informing users that
>   the old API will soon be retired.

But it seems that from a couple of days it suddenly stop working without any changes from our side.

It just doesn't load the captcha image anymore.

In the console I see only this warning message:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

I'd like to know if there is anyone else who is facing this issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's fixed now**. We also had the same issue for the last 24 hours but it looks like Google has fixed their API response and are no longer using document.write(). Make sure you are using 'ajax=1' in the url to request the challenge. 
Something like: `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=public_api_key_here&ajax=1&lang=en`

Comment: I confirm that has been fixed 48 hours later. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions) says something different:

> reCAPTCHA V1 - Unsupported
>
> reCAPTCHA V1 has been deprecated since May of 2016 and will not work for new sites. reCAPTCHA v1 is no longer supported and **continued functionality can not be guaranteed**. Please switch to one of the options above.

(emphasis is mine)

Maybe something changed in their backend and now it's not working with your settings/API calls.